# Xcode custom segue animation

Tags: xcode, animation, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a problem with the transition animation between two storyboard controllers. 
I have a singleView project with two view controllers in the storyboard.

Now I wand to make a custom transition animation:

- my current view controller should disappear to the left
- the new view controller should come from the right

I have already a `UIStoryboardSegue` class.

But what should I write in the `-(void)perform{}` method??

Thanks a lot,

Jonas.

Comment: Just write "custom segue" in google and you will find many example. First do some try and than come here with what you have tried. one example : http://blog.jimjh.com/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-storyboard-segues.html

Comment: And BTW what animation you want is default push segue animation you don't have to write code for that.

Comment: @CRDave-- only if you want to use a UINavigationController.  If you don't want to use that controller, then you have to custom code the same transition.  Seems silly that xcode breaks mvc so hard (ie, that you can only get a certain transition if you have a certain controller), but there it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For that simple segue you can try something like this:

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController* source = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController* destination = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;

    CGRect sourceFrame = source.view.frame;
    sourceFrame.origin.x = -sourceFrame.size.width;

    CGRect destFrame = destination.view.frame;
    destFrame.origin.x = destination.view.frame.size.width;
    destination.view.frame = destFrame;

    destFrame.origin.x = 0;

    [source.view.superview addSubview:destination.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         source.view.frame = sourceFrame;
                         destination.view.frame = destFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         UIWindow *window = source.view.window;
                         [window setRootViewController:destination];
                     }];
}
```