# What does the System Preferences app in macOS use for navigating between an item and its details when NSNavigationController doesn't exist in cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa

For instance, when the user clicks the Desktop & Screen Saver item, the System Preferences app navigates to the item's specific view controller.

I understand that the buttons in the top (e.g., navigation buttons) are toolbar items, but how about the body when there's no VC similar to iOS's `UINavigationController`?

Currently, I'm using `NSPageController` along with my own complicated abstractions, but I'm thinking there should be a better way to do such basic functionality.

Comment: Preference panes are plugins. "The preference application serves as the container of the preference pane: It loads the preference pane plug-in and provides the window in which the preference pane is displayed." See [Preference Pane Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Concepts/Architecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000701-BAJECHGA).

Comment: Or is the question [How does one display a new view controller in the same Mac window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139294/how-does-one-display-a-new-view-controller-in-the-same-mac-window)